# Java convert stereo to left-center-right

Tags: java, audio

I am trying to convert stereo audio to a 3-channel left-center-right audio. My input stream is a PCM bytestream converted to an array of doubles(0-1) per frame, thus removing the complexity of having to deal with different samplesizes:

```
double[] stereoFrame = new double[2]; // Left = 0, right = 1
double[] lCrFrame = new double[3]; // Left = 0, center = 1 right = 2
```

So far I have come up with the following procedure, but I am not sure if this is the right way to process the audio:

```
... Processing input filling stereoFrame ...

// Calculating center
lCrFrame[1] = (stereoFrame[0] + stereoFrame[1])/2;
// Calculating left side -> diff left side to center
lCrFrame[0] = stereoFrame[0] - lCrFrame[1];
// Calculating right side -> diff right side to center
lCrFrame[2] = stereoFrame[1] - lCrFrame[1];
```

Is this indeed the right way to transform stereo to l-c-r? If not, can you point me to the right way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: I think you could just use Left and Right channels as they come from the stereo stream, and for the Center channel I'd use the average of the two.

Comment: But wouldn't it be louder if I only average the two to center?

Comment: dividing the sum of the channels by two (i.e. getting the average) actually equates to reducing 3 dB of the signal ... it would be louder if you'd just sum both.